# Authenticate object returning null : Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to get the user using `Authentication` as follows, but `getAuthentication()` is returning `null`.

I think the reason is the load by username method is not getting called.

```java
@Bean
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public AppUser user() {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    return (AppUser) auth.getPrincipal();
}
```

**Security Config Class :**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String DEFAULT_USER = "ROLE_USER";
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private boolean disablePrincipalChanges;
    @Autowired
    private AppPreAuthUserDetailsService preAuthUserDetailsService;


    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Inside configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)..");

        auth.authenticationProvider(preAuthAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preAuthAuthenticationProvider() {
        log.info("Inside preAuthAuthenticationProvider()");
        UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> wrapper = null;
        wrapper = new UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken>(preAuthUserDetailsService);
        PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
        preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(wrapper);
        return preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public Filter preAuthFilter() throws Exception {
        log.info("Inside preAuthFilter");
        RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter filter = new RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setPrincipalRequestHeader("sm_user");
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        filter.setCheckForPrincipalChanges(disablePrincipalChanges);
        filter.setInvalidateSessionOnPrincipalChange(disablePrincipalChanges);
        return filter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        log.info("Configuring pre-auth");
        http
                .csrf().disable();
        http
                .addFilter(preAuthFilter());
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().hasAuthority(UserAuthoritiesEnum.VIEW.getCNUserAuthoritiesEnum());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        log.info("Inside configure(WebSecurity web)..");

        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/webjars/**", "/js/**", "/css/**");
    }
}
```

**AppPreAuthUserDetailsService :**

```
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

/**
 *
 */
@Service
public class AppPreAuthUserDetailsService extends PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService implements
        UserDetailsService {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String clientUserId) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        log.info("Load User By loadUserByUsername" + clientUserId);
        System.out.println("Success");

        AppUser clientUser = new AppUser();
        clientUser.setUserId(clientUserId);
        return clientUser;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Of course it will return `null`... The scoped proxy is being created before Spring Security will have had a change to invoke its filters. I suggest not to use this way to try to get hold of your current user...

Comment: @M.Deinum loadUserByUsername method is not getting invoked even after bean is created.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the fact if it is being invoked or not. Even if it would be invoked afterwards it would return `null`.